# There is a numpy.dot documentation example which is not clear, with high-dimensional dot-product

Tags: python, numpy

I was reading numpy documentation for better clarification, when I come across an example it was not very clear. I copy the exact example from numpy documentation below:

```
a = np.arange(3*4*5*6).reshape((3,4,5,6))
b = np.arange(3*4*5*6)[::-1].reshape((5,4,6,3))
np.dot(a, b)[2,3,2,1,2,2]
```

The question is, in the last line `np.dot(a,b)[2,3,2,1,2,2]` what is `[2,3,2,1,2,2]` doing behind the `np.dot(a,b)`?

Comment: It is indexing of the result array produced by `dot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: My previous answer was wrong!**

When you have arrays higher than degree 2 'dotted' together using `np.dot` you have to specifiy which axes you are multipying & summing over.

In the example the `[2,3,2,1,2,2]` is reference to which axes are chosen in `a` & `b` repectively.

> From the docs:
>
> If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum
>   product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:
>
> dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])

So in our case we have,

```
a[2,3,2,:] = [342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347]
b[1,2,:,2] = [249, 246, 243, 240, 237, 234]
```

And when you dot them,

```
np.dot([249, 246, 243, 240, 237, 234], [342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347])
```

You get `499128`

You get the same answer when you use `np.dot(a[2,3,2,:], b[1,2,:,2])` or shorthand `np.dot(a, b)[2,3,2,1,2,2]`

When you dont use any index my assumption is that you get every permuation of the above hence the counter intutive dimensions of `c = np.dot(a, b)`

**EDIT #2** The reason for the shape of `c` is that if you index `c[2,3,2,1,2,2]` as per the example then you will get the corresponding answer`499128`.

Comment: very well said. but can you say why dot operation of a 4-D and another 4-D array is a 6-D array?

Comment: a.shape = (3, 4, 5, 6),  b.shape = (5, 4, 6, 3). Why is their dot-product shape (4, 5, 5, 4, 3)? Please explain more clearly in your answer.